# Supabase: filter rows based on if any of their one to many relations has property

Tags: javascript, sql, supabase, supabase-database

In supabase I have a list of tracks and each track can have multiple artists (kept in a separate table). I only want tracks in which at least one of the artists associated with that track contains a certain property, we'll say their genre has to equal rap.

```
  tracksWithAtLeast1ArtistWhoseGenreIsRap = await supabase
      .from("tracks")
      .select("name, artists ( genre ), id")
      .filter("artists.genre", "eq", "rap")
```

here is what i'm workin right right now but the issue is that I think this filters the selected artists within each track by genre rather than filtering the tracks based on if any of its artists has the genre "rap".

Comment: Is artists a separate table?  Please elaborate more about your db schema.

Comment: Yes, I updated the post to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `!inner` keyword to filter your top level table (tracks) by its relational table (artists).

In the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#filtering-with-inner-joins), it says

> If you want to filter a table based on a child table's values you can use the !inner() function. For example, if you wanted to select all rows in a message table which belong to a user with the username "Jane":

In your case, the query could look like this:

```js
tracksWithAtLeast1ArtistWhoseGenreIsRap = await supabase
 .from("tracks")
 .select("name, artists!inner( genre ), id")
 .eq("artists.genre", "rap")
```

You can read more about `!inner` in our documentation [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#filtering-with-inner-joins)!